# UnicodeDecodeError Error charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 250:

Tags: python, django, imagefield, filefield

```html
class ProductDownloadlView(MultiSlugMixin,DetailView):
    model=Product
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        obj=self.get_object()
        filepath = os.path.join(settings.PROTECTED_ROOT,obj.media.path)
        guessed_type = guess_type(filepath)[0]
        wrapper=FileWrapper(open(filepath))
        mimetype = 'application/force-download'
        if guessed_type:
            mimetype=guessed_type
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type=mimetype)
        if request.GET.get("preview"):
            response["Content-Disposition"]="attachment; filename=%s" %(obj.media.name)
        response["X-SendFile"]=str(obj.media.name)
        return response
```

am using python 3.7 and django 1.8.6 trying to download files like .txt works fine and .md files but i have tried an image file and it gives the error charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 250: character maps to 
from the template list products

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block Content %}
<h1>Products</h1>
<p>{{object.title}} </p>
<p>{{object.description}} </p>
<p>{{object.price}}</p>
{% if object.media %}
<p>{{ object.media }}</p>
<p><a href="{{ object.get_download }}">Download</a></p>
<p><a href="{{ object.get_download }}?preview=True">Preview</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock Content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's HttpResponse class is most suitable for a text based response (html page, txt file, etc.). The [documentation for the class constructor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__) explains:

> content should be an iterator or a string. If it’s an iterator, it should return strings, and those strings will be joined together to form the content of the response. If it is not an iterator or a string, it will be converted to a string when accessed.

You UnicodeDecodeError is probably raised when the `content` is converted to a string. If you want to return a PDF file, the file content is binary data, so it is not intended to be converted to string.

You may use the [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) class instead. It inherits from StreamingHttpResponse, and so have a different APi than HttpResponse, but it will probably works better to return a binary file (like a PDF).

Comment: can you suggest where to edit because what i want to return should be a jpg file or just the format of the file i have uploaded

Comment: I think you should return FileRespone instead of HttpResponse.
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/86007/django.http.FileResponse

Comment: yeah of course i have used  wrapper=FileWrapper(open(filepath,'rb'))

Comment: also response = FileResponse(wrapper,content_type=mimetype) worked i dont know even what am doing with these two options